# Changing Dropdown SelectList when a different dropdownlist item is selected RAZOR

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, selectlist

I have a dropdown that contains a list of companies and i have another dropdown that contains a list of company branches. I need to make the branches dropdown dependent on the company selected item. So when the user selects company1 from the dropdown then the branch dropdown should populate the list to the branches that are in company1. I am not sure how to do this. Here is what my drop downs look like:

```
            <tr>
                <td class="search-label">
                    @Html.Label("Company: ")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("cono", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CompanyList)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="search-label">
                    @Html.Label("Branch: ")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("branch", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BranchList)
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Here is my Action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        var currentUserCono = GetCurrentUserCono();
        //Set the Viewbags to populate the drop down menus on the view
        if (Session["cono"] != null)
        {
            currentUserCono = (int)Session["cono"];
        }
        ViewBag.CompanyList = _selectListLib.GetCompanies(currentUserCono);
        ViewBag.BranchList = Session["branch"] != null ? _selectListLib.GetBranches(currentUserCono,(string)Session["branch"]) : _selectListLib.GetBranches(currentUserCono);
        ViewBag.StatusTypeList = Session["statustype"] != null ? _selectListLib.GetStatusTypes((bool)Session["statustype"]) : _selectListLib.GetStatusTypes();

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Just use my jquery plugin https://github.com/fals/jquery-cascadeselect this will make your life easy

Comment: Cascading using Ajax will solve it.

Comment: Yeap @ArijitMukherjee, thats what my plugin does automatically!!! :D https://github.com/fals/jquery-cascadeselect

Comment: Thank you guys! I am going to look into this. It looks like my best option right now haha

Answer (score 0):

You have two (more, but two major) popular techniques:

- Create an Action (JSONResult) with company id as a parameter that returns the Branches, serialized into JSON. Then use jQuery to retrieve that list via $.getJSON bound to
  the jQuery .change() event of the Company dropdownlist. You can then
  iterate through that JSON list and add option elements to the Branch
  dropdownlist.

Or

- Create an Action (PartialViewResult) with company id as a parameter that returns a partial view containing your branch dropdownlist, populated with the relevant branches in  the view. Use jQuery's .load() to load that view, again bound to the jQuery .change() event on the Company dropdownlist. For this to work, you will need to use an ID on your  element surrounding the branch in order to target it for $("#yourTDId").load("/Controller/Action/" + $("#cono").val())

Those are the easiest two ways of accomplishing what you need. I hope this helps and good luck with your app.